# Python: list index out of range error, so how do I call the index correctly?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python assignment to chart BMI and age against each other on a scatter plot. I'm encountering an error splitting and pulling the data from the .dat file with the list index. I gather that the error means the index of the data is not where I'm calling it, but how do I call it correctly? The complete code executed properly when my partner ran it in on a lab machine- could different versions account for the error?

The relevant code is:

```
for line in fname:
    a = line.split()
    weight = a[22]
    height = a[23]
    bmi = float(weight) / ((float(height) / 100) ** 2)
    age = float(a[21])
    age_list.append(age)
    bmi_list.append(bmi)
    fname.close()


# The relevant part of the error is:
weight = a[23]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It means that you have less than 24 values in your `line` variable, so there is no 23rd element (starting from zero).

Comment: Use `len(a)` to check the size of the list. `a[-1]` will get the last element, `a[-2]` the second from last element, ...

Comment: You said _The relevant part of the error is: weight = a[23]_ but in your code `weight` var is assigned with the value of `a[23]`. The exception is raised on `weight` or `height`?

Comment: That was a typo on my part, @Victor M. The error is raised with the first one encountered; I accidentally copied the error from when I tried having height first.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of a. Hope a contains less than 23 elements. You can even check the length of a using len(a) function before accessing a[23]

Answer (score 0):

If you opened `fname` in Excel (or many other spreadsheet viewer) after your partner used it at the lab, it's quite possible that the spreadsheet viewer converted your separators within `fname` from whitespace (eg. tabs) to commas, meaning the `line.split()` will result in `a` being `len == 1`.

Try opening `fname` in a text editor to see if the seperators are still `whitespace`, or change `line.split()` to `line.split(',')` to see if that helps.

Comment: I downloaded a fresh copy and the errors still occur, unfortunately.

Comment: Try and open the new file in a text editor and see what the delimiter is. Also, if you post a small example of some of the data, I'm sure I can get the code to work

Comment: Another thing, and I'm sure you know this, but Python is zero-indexed, so if you count the number of columns, you need to start counting at 0. So the 23rd column would be `x[22]`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find out the length of your list via typing: 

`list_length = len(a)`

But in your case you only get a list with a length of 1 item. If you want to get list of all lines given, then I would suggest using **line.splitlines()**.

But be careful, the first entry of a list has the index 0, so the highest index of an item in your list can be **len(a) - 1**. Otherwise Python will raise an IndexError as you just recognized!

I hope that helped you.

~rotsechs

Comment: Unfortunately, 'a' keeps coming back as "not defined", which is most puzzling since the first thing I do is define 'a'. I don't see anything in the later code that would override that.

Comment: Thinking about it, that's probably the root cause: a is not defined, therefore the index was out of range (I sure wish that error couldn't be cause by 1000 different things, as I found when researching before asking here). I still have no idea why it's occurring, though. 'a' is properly defined as being the split list from line, yet 'a' cannot be called.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was further up the chain: fname was being defined incorrectly, and a line had been lost when code was added to combine two functions. The problem existed between the keyboard and the chair. Thanks for all your input and help, everyone!